# Flask & AJAX - Capturing a click AND THEN updating photos

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

- I have a list of ~100 urls to photos
- Python grabs the list, randomizes it and assigns left and right to 0 and 1 respectively
- home.html renders with both photos
- Within my js script, if either photo is clicked, it returns which photo was clicked
- Then I'm trying to update left and right with the next two photos in the list, but I just can't get it to work :(

**Question is:**
How can I update home.html with p_left and p_right?

**engine.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import random
from photostorage import photos

rand_photo_list = random.sample(photos, len(photos))
p_left_num = 0
p_right_num = 1

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    p_left = rand_photo_list[p_left_num]
    p_right = rand_photo_list[p_right_num]
    return render_template('home.html', p_left=p_left, p_right=p_right)

@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    data = request.get_data()

    global p_left_num
    global p_right_num
    p_left_num = p_left_num + 2
    p_right_num = p_right_num + 2
    p_left = rand_photo_list[p_left_num]
    p_right = rand_photo_list[p_right_num]


    return jsonify({'p_left': p_left, 'p_right': p_right})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.image').on('click', function() {

        var img_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var img_url = $(this).attr('src');

        req = $.ajax({
            url: '/update',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({img_id: img_id, img_url: img_url})
        });

        req.done(function(payload){

            $('#p_left').attr('src').replaceWith(payload.p_left)
            $('#p_right').attr('src').replaceWith(payload.p_right)

        });

    });
});
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Start</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <img class='image' src="{{p_left}}" id='p_left' width="40%">
    <img class='image' src="{{p_right}}" id='p_right' width="40%">

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

The error I'm getting in the console is as follows:

```
> main.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).replaceWith is not a
> function
>     at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:27)
>     at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>     at A (jquery.min.js:4)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Comment: So what is not working?  What happens when one of the photos is clicked? Are there any frontend or backend errors?

Comment: `$.ajax()` takes a `complete` keyword argument with a callback function, I guess that's where you need to call your payload function.

Comment: @fsimonjetz The OP uses the `.done()` callback, that's the same thing.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: change this `$('#p_left').attr('src').replaceWith(payload.p_left)` to `$('#p_left').attr('src' ,payload.p_left)` and same for other .